# JMS Queue corrupted after reboot of server, throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I am using an embedded JMS (ActiveMQ) in Tomcat. When the server shutdown and rebooted, it now shows the error:

```
ERROR | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@3443416b:MyQueue,batchResetNeeded=false,size=1,cacheEnabled=false,maxBatchSize:1,hasSpace:true,pendingCachedIds.size:0,lastSyncCachedId:null,lastSyncCachedId-seq:null,lastAsyncCachedId:null,lastAsyncCachedId-seq:null,store=permits:10000,sd=nextSeq:1,lastRet:MessageOrderCursor:[def:0, low:0, high:0],pending:0 - Failed to fill batch
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.loadMessage(KahaDBStore.java:1248)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$4.execute(KahaDBStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:779)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(KahaDBStore.java:582)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(ProxyMessageStore.java:110)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch.doFillBatch(QueueStorePrefetch.java:120)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:420)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:163)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.StoreQueueCursor.reset(StoreQueueCursor.java:169)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doPageInForDispatch(Queue.java:1941)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.pageInMessages(Queue.java:2170)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.iterate(Queue.java:1607)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@3443416b:MyQueue,batchResetNeeded=false,size=1,cacheEnabled=false,maxBatchSize:1,hasSpace:true,pendingCachedIds.size:0,lastSyncCachedId:null,lastSyncCachedId-seq:null,lastAsyncCachedId:null,lastAsyncCachedId-seq:null,store=permits:10000,sd=nextSeq:1,lastRet:MessageOrderCursor:[def:0, low:0, high:0],pending:0 - Failed to fill batch
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:423)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:163)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.StoreQueueCursor.reset(StoreQueueCursor.java:169)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doPageInForDispatch(Queue.java:1941)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.pageInMessages(Queue.java:2170)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.iterate(Queue.java:1607)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.loadMessage(KahaDBStore.java:1248)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$4.execute(KahaDBStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:779)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(KahaDBStore.java:582)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(ProxyMessageStore.java:110)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch.doFillBatch(QueueStorePrefetch.java:120)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:420)
        ... 10 more
ERROR | Failed to page in more queue messages 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:166)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.StoreQueueCursor.reset(StoreQueueCursor.java:169)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doPageInForDispatch(Queue.java:1941)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.pageInMessages(Queue.java:2170)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.iterate(Queue.java:1607)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:423)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:163)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaTraceCommand cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.data.KahaAddMessageCommand
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.loadMessage(KahaDBStore.java:1248)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$4.execute(KahaDBStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:779)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(KahaDBStore.java:582)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(ProxyMessageStore.java:110)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch.doFillBatch(QueueStorePrefetch.java:120)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:420)
        ... 10 more
```

1. Why does this occur?
2. How do I recover from this?

Is there anything I can do in the configuration, or in my code to prevent this and/or recover from it?

Comment: Which version of AMQ are you using? And was it a graceful shut-down & reboot or something else?

Comment: @user3788685 I'm using the latest version. I shut it down using `sudo reboot now`.

Comment: Does it happen if you just stop/start/restart the activemq broker or just on a host reboot? I run 5.14.3 without any issues - but I did have problems with the newest 2 versions (mostly on the stats side of things)

Comment: @user3788685 Just on server reboot - but not always. It only happens if the reboot occurs just as messages are being sent/acknolwedged/recovered. It's an issue with the base persistence of ActiveMQ. If I switch to using MySQL as the persistence, the issue never occurs.

Comment: I've not noticed that issue - but I *always* gracefully shutdown my aqm instance before any reboot. I've just noticed they have released 5.15.0 which fixes lots of things so it might be worth a look through the changelog/jira or a test deployment to see if the error is resolved. If I get a chance over the weekend I'll try and reproduce the issue with my test instance.(But the *last* version gave me other issues mostly round the monitoring interface so couldn't use it in production)